# Permission Denied For Folders in Mounted VHDX/VHD in WSL (Windows 10)

Tags: windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have created a VHDX (GUID type) file in Windows 10. 
It is mounted as an NTFS formatted drive with drive letter **X:**. When I open the bash (Ubuntu on Windows 10/WSL), I am able to

```
cd /mnt/x
```

However, when I do ls, i get permission denied for all the files. Also, I am not able to create directory even with sudo. Same problem with chmod, chown, etc.

I have also tried to grant permissions to everyone through **icacls** in Windows through command line **as well as through the GUI**.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OpQ6D.png]

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2vlOI.png]

---

**Updates [Edit]**
I think the problem is that the way NTFS gets mounted on Windows. The mounted mode is being treated as a read-only mode by the Ubuntu Bash.

Comment: I have posted a similar question at: https://github.com/Microsoft/BashOnWindows/issues/1199

Comment: I too have the same problem.

Comment: Have you tried with recent versions? Apparently, the problem has been solved in [Windows Build 17713](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/release-notes#build-17713) and the reported bug [have been closed](https://superuser.com/questions/1332176/how-do-i-recover-my-legacy-wsl-without-data-loss/1344205#1344205).